# disable a CheckBox depending on dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working on a asp.net mvc3 application with DropDownLists and CheckBoxes and so on.

I wrote a javascript to disable a CheckBox if a defined option of a dropdownlist is selected:

```
$(function() {
    $('#dropdownlistId').change(function() {
        if (this.value == '1st option') {
          $('#checkboxId').attr('disabled', disabled);
        } else {
          $('#checkboxId').removeAttr('disabled', disabled);
        }
    });
});
```

this works fine, but the script reacts only on a ***change*** of the dropdownlist

so if '1st option' is on the top of the dropdownlist and so automatically selected as default, the script doesn't disable the checkbox. Only if the user select another option and select '1st option' once again...

Please help me :)

PS: the script also doesn't work if I use my keyboard to switch the dropdownlist options instead of my mouse

So it would be very kind if you could help my to improve the script, because I really can't do javascript :/

Comment: Please include the html or better yet make a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var $cb = $('#checkboxId');
    $('#dropdownlistId').change(function() {
        if (this.value == '1st option') {
          $cb.prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
          $cb.prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

The difference in triggering change event after adding halnderl. About your second question - Using keyboard the 'change' event will be triggered when select will lose focus ('blur').

Comment: thx, I slightly modified your code and it solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
function setCheckBox() {
     if (this.value == '1st option') {
        $('#checkboxId').attr('disabled', disabled);
      } else {
         $('#checkboxId').removeAttr('disabled', disabled);
      }
}
$(function() {
    setCheckBox();//do this on load..
    $('#dropdownlistId').change(function() {
      setCheckBox();//and on change
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define your CheckBox control, use disabled attribute to disable it by default.  That way it will be disabled already and there is no need to add more javascript to disable it from the get go.

It would look something like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsCheckBox, new { @disabled = "true" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be little incorrect depends on your need because your calling the disable function on change of that dropdown list you need to write it in document.ready like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {if(document.getElementById("dropdownlistId").value="1stoption")
{
document.getElementById('checkboxId').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
else
{//do something whatever you wish here in else condition

}
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    var $cb = $('#checkboxId');
    $('#dropdownlistId').change(function() {
        if (this.value == '1st option') {
          $cb.attr('disabled', disabled);
        } else {
          $cb.removeAttr('disabled', disabled);
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

works like a charm now
thank you guys